# Writing a program to convert int to roman numerals, but I am a little stuck:

Tags: java

I am writing this program for my first intro to programming class so I am still pretty new to coding. This is what I have so far in my conversion class:

```
/**
 * Write a description of class Conversion here.
 *
 * @author (your name)
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class Conversion
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private int num;
    private String Roman;
    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Conversion
     */
    public Conversion(int num, String Roman)
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        num = num;
        Roman = Roman;
    }

    /**
     * An example of a method - replace this comment with your own
     *
     * @param  y  a sample parameter for a method
     * @return    the sum of x and y
     */
    public static String convert(int num)
    {
        // put your code here
        String Roman= " ";
        num = num;
        int thousand = num / 1000;
        int hundred = num / 100;
        int ten = num / 10;



        switch (thousand) {
            case 1: Roman += "M";
            break;
            case 2: Roman += "MM";
            break;
            case 3: Roman += "MM";
            break;
            default: Roman += "Invalid";
            break;


        }


        switch (hundred) {
            case 1: Roman += "C";
            break;
            case 2: Roman += "CC";
            break;
            case 3: Roman += "CCC";
            break;
            case 4: Roman += "CD";
            break;
            case 5: Roman += "D";
            break;
            case 6: Roman += "DC";
            break;
            case 7: Roman += "DCC";
            break;
            case 8: Roman += "DCCC";
            break;
            case 9: Roman += "CM";
            break;
            default: Roman += "Invalid";
            break;


        }

        switch (ten) {
            case 1: Roman += "X";
            break;
            case 2: Roman += "XX";
            break;
            case 3: Roman += "XXX";
            break;
            case 4: Roman += "XL";
            break;
            case 5: Roman += "L";
            break;
            case 6: Roman += "LX";
            break;
            case 7: Roman += "LXX";
            break;
            case 8: Roman += "LXXX";
            break;
            case 9: Roman += "XC";
            break;
            default: Roman += "Invalid";
            break;

        }

        switch (num) {
            case 1: Roman += "I";
            break;
            case 2: Roman += "II";
            break;
            case 3: Roman += "III";
            break;
            case 4: Roman += "IV";
            break;
            case 5: Roman += "V";
            break;
            case 6: Roman += "VI";
            break;
            case 7: Roman += "VII";
            break;
            case 8: Roman += "VIII";
            break;
            case 9: Roman += "IX";
            break;
            default: Roman += "Invalid";
            break;

        }
        return Roman;    
    }   



}

This is my Scanner class to see if the code functions:

    import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 * Write a description of class Lab7 here.
 *
 * @author (your name)
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class Lab7
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private int num;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Lab7
     */
    public Lab7(int num)
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        this.num = num;
    }

    /**
     * An example of a method - replace this comment with your own
     *
     * @param  y  a sample parameter for a method
     * @return    the sum of x and y
     */
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        // put your code here
        Scanner Roman = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to integer to Roman numeral conversion program");
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Please enter an integer in the range 1-3999 (both inclusive): ");
        int num = Roman.nextInt();

        do {
            System.out.println(num + " In Roman numerals is: " + Conversion.convert(num));
        }while (num <= 3999 && num >= 1);
    }
}
```

When I run the code I get an infinite loop that keeps printing ... In Roman numerals is: MInvalid

I am very stuck and not sure where to go next. Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: Edit: The output is actually MInvalidInvalidInvalid, so it goes through the first switch statement and it works, then it just jumps to the invalid for the next three.

Comment: Please do not add information in comments. [edit] your post and include new or additional information directly in the question.

Comment: Please only edit your question; don't add additional info as comments. That said: As written, this would require people to load up and run your app to see the error. Further: You haven't shared what input you used when testing, what output (if any) you got, and what result you expected. So, it's essentially "why isn't my code working" - which is an off-topic type of question. Please edit to be specific.

Comment: Think about it. If `num == 1000`, `hundred == 10`. This will enter the default `switch` case and append `Invalid` to your string. This would have been shown if you used a debugger to inspect the values of your variables.

Comment: Use a debugger to step through the code to see where it's not doing what you expect.

Answer (score 2):

You should try using a debugger, or just printing your variables. For example, when your `switch(hundred)` appends 'invalid' to the String, this means that `hundred` is not a number 1-9, so what is it? There is something else you need to be doing in the `convert` method.

The loop is infinite because, well, you don't change the value of `num` in the loop, and look at the loop condition. Just as a guess, without your exact assignment specification, I would expect that the loop in `main` for a simple program like this would do something like the following:

```
do {
    // take user input
} while (/* input is invalid */);
```

edit: Sometimes the loop is also something like this:

```
do {
    // take user input
    // do something and print some output
} while (/* input is not the special value which should exit */);
```

Answer (score -1):

Few changes: -

1. "Conversion" Constructor: - "this" keyword is used to refer current class instance variable.

   ```
   this.num = num
   this.Roman = Roman;
   ```
2. Convert Method: - 
    Include new variable "ones" to hold the last digit instead of "num" in the last Switch loop.

   ```
   int thousand = num / 1000;
   int hundred = (num%1000) / 100;
   int ten = (num % 100)/10;
   int ones = num%10;
   ```
3. do-while loop in the Main method: - 
   Your conditions are completely opposite. Change to:-

   ```
   while (num >= 3999 && num <= 1);
   ```

Hope this helps :)